# Ignite client failover

Tags: client, ignite, failover

We have this Ignite cluster configuration: there are several servers + 1 client, which acts as a balancer. For example, IP addresses are:

server1 - 192.168.100.1
server2 - 192.168.100.2
server3 - 192.168.100.3

client - 192.168.100.100

So requests go to the client - for example http://192.168.100.100:8082/request1

Then the client sends the Distributed Computing Task to the cluster - the calculations are performed on one of the servers, so on 192.168.100.1 or 192.168.100.2 or 192.168.100.3. Results of calculations then return to client, then client finally sends response to the request.

There is no problem if one of the servers crashes - client would be knowing about that and wouldn't send Task on that server. But there is a problem if the client crashes - all servers work, but the address http://192.168.100.100:8080/request1 is not available.

What can I do about it? Can client be failover? Does Ignite have something for that? If not, what other technology/software can I use?

Comment: How do you connect to the client? You may use generic TCP or even HTTP balancer in front of multiple Ignite thick clients serving thin client connections.

Comment: Then what is the point of using Ignite thick client? - I thought it is their whole purpose - to be a balancer.

Comment: Yes, but you need more than one thick client for reliability. You can list all of your thick clients in comma-separated fashion in your thin clients' connection address: "192.168.100.100,192.168.100.101,192.168.100.102"